# Why does Azure say params are missing from my ARM Template when I provision with CLI?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-cli

Here's the Azure CLI command I'm using:

`az deployment group create --resource-group example_rg_name --template-file arm_templates/my_project_folder/template.json --no-prompt`

Here's the resulting error:
 `InvalidTemplate - Deployment template validation failed: 'The value for the template parameter 'location' at line '5' and column '21' is not provided. Please see https://aka.ms/resource-manager-parameter-files for usage details.'.`

Here is the allegedly invalid line 5:

```
1 {
2     "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
3     "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
4     "parameters": {
5         "location": {
6             "type": "String"
7         },
...
```

Indeed, the value for location here only includes the type.  HOWEVER, the location IS present in the parameters.json file, see line 6 below:

```
1 {
2     "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
3     "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
4     "parameters": {
5         "location": {
6             "value": "westus2"  
7         },
```

And notice how this value is referenced in the template.json file, for example line 51 below:

```
46 "resources": [
47         {
48             "type": "Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces",
49             "apiVersion": "2018-04-01",
50            "name": "[parameters('workspaceName')]",
51            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
52            "dependsOn": [
```

Do I need to hard code the values in place of these references?  This template and parameters file were exported from Azure after manually creating the service, which by the way is a databricks service.

Any hints as to what I'm missing here?

THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference your parameters file when creating the deployment.

az deployment group create --resource-group example_rg_name
--template-file arm_templates/my_project_folder/template.json **--parameters @parameters.json** --no-prompt